# Scripting with Lua in Libgdx

Tags: plugins, lua, libgdx, game-engine

Recently I started to learn Lua.

I have been developing games in Libgdx for almost six months. I know how to work properly with this library but I still haven't found out which uses does Lua have for developing games. I mean, what can I do with Lua and Libgdx?

For those of you who are still wondering, I would like to get some examples, if I may.

Thanks!

Comment: To give you an example what you can do with lua in games (not only with libgdx): Do you know the Minecraft Mod "ComputerCraft" (http://www.computercraft.info). In this mod you program Computers with LUA. Those computers can then do some tasks for you, like digging mines, sending out a redstone signal etc. What you could do for example is use Lua scripts for AI-behaivor. This would make it possible to have many different AI-behaivors, by just giving then other AI-scripts. It would also be possible to let the player write some Scripts for different entities.

Comment: Short answer: a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scripting languages such as lua for many things. For example, you can define the behavior of players, AI, common variables, and much of the logic in scripts. You can easily build a console into your game and edit scripts and pass commands via that console on runtime, rather than reloading the game. I personally use Lua to do event-handling (eg "if player is in pos XYZ, then do this and that and fire event T from nextEvent.lua").

I use the built in text file format included in the gdx-ai module to define the behaviors of the nations in my game, and I have created my own localisation format so as to support multiple languages and easily modify item descriptions.

I use XML to handle my GUI. In short you can do a great many things by scripting as well as using a data-oriented format.